# Error with creating Private Key in Python 3 RSA

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, rsa, private-key

I'm trying to create a random RSA Private key in Python but I'm getting a Error message and I don't know what to do.
The code I'm using now is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42175763/error-while-creating-private-key-with-rsa-in-python/42175843#42175843) Thread I created earlier, but I won't work.

Code:

```
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

def random_generator():
    return Random.new().read(32)

private_key = RSA.generate(1024, random_generator)
print(str(private_key))
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/simon/Python/Projects/FileServer/encrypt.py", line 7, in <module>
    private_key = RSA.generate(1024, random_generator)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 508, in generate
    obj = _RSA.generate_py(bits, rf, progress_func, e)    # TODO: Don't use legacy _RSA module
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/_RSA.py", line 50, in generate_py
    p = pubkey.getStrongPrime(bits>>1, obj.e, 1e-12, randfunc)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Crypto/Util/number.py", line 265, in getStrongPrime
    randfunc)
TypeError: random_generator() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while creating private key with RSA in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42175763/error-while-creating-private-key-with-rsa-in-python)

Comment: Don't repost, you can [edit] your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA-module.html):

> `generate(bits, randfunc=None, progress_func=None, e=65537)`
>
> Parameters:
>
> ...
>
> - `randfunc` (callable) - Random number generation function; it should accept a single integer N and return a string of random data N bytes long. If not specified, a new one will be instantiated from Crypto.Random.

Your `random_generator()` doesn't take any parameters. It is supposed to take one parameter - the number of byes to return. Also the implementation is bad - you're creating a new instance every time which could seriously weaken the randomness of the numbers it generates.

But since you're just using a `Crypto.Random` instance there's no need for you to specify this parameter at all - just leave it out.

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

private_key = RSA.generate(1024)
print(str(private_key))
```

---

If you *insist* on providing your own randfunc, pass it the bound `read` method of a `Crypto.Random` instance:

```
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

r = Random.new()

private_key = RSA.generate(1024, r.read)
print(str(private_key))
```

Comment: Thanks so far, how could I implement it better?

Comment: I updated the answer to show you how to provide a good randfunc. Please also consider up-voting the answer if it was useful for you.

Comment: When or why would I use my own randfunc? Or should I simply never use one? And I can't vote

Comment: There's probably no reason to ever provide your own random function, unless you're trying to deliberately weaken the generated key. I thought all users could up-vote.